# ID сообщения в беседе vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу бота на vk_api. Возникла проблема что при отправке сообщения в беседу возвращается не уникальный id сообщения а ноль, в то время как в личных сообщениях все нормально возвращается. Например

```
test = vk_api.messages.send(peer_id = peer_id, message = "test")
```

Значение test будет числом - id сообщения если речь идет о личных сообщениях, но зануляется если сообщение отправлено в беседу. Пробовал написать все без библиотек на чистом requests, в ответ сервер выдает json

```
{'responce': 0}
```

С чем может быть связана данная проблема и как ее решить (мб даже и через костыль, но лучше более-менее адекватно

Comment: Проблема связана с тем, что ВК не даст Вам уникальный id сообщения из беседы, если у бота нет полного доступа к переписке беседы.

Answer (score 0):

API ВКонтакте закрыло сообществам возможность получения ID сообщений для бесед. Читайте следующие материалы:

1. [API для чат-ботов › 1. Сообщество › 1.2. Добавление ботов в беседы](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs?f=1.2.%20%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B)
2. [Roadmap › Ограничение Messages API](https://vk.com/dev/messages_api)

Костыль есть: сохраняйте историю сообщений в базе, ведите свой учёт ID сообщений или ограничьтесь упоминаниями вашего бота и ответами на его сообщения.